# Creating different wheels for different OSes, from one host OS

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I have a package that includes binaries for five different OS and architecture combinations: Windows 32- and 64-bit, Linux 32- and 64-bit, and OS X (fat). The contents of `setup.py` can be found [here](https://github.com/aarzee/airship/blob/master/airship.steamcloud/setup.py).

I am aware that it is possible (and indeed preferable) to upload platform-specific wheels to PyPI instead of uploading one wheel containing binaries for all platforms or even a source distribution, the latter of which I cannot do because some of the binaries are proprietary (but redistributable).

My question is, how would I go about creating separate wheels for each platform? Specifically:

- Can I use multiple setup scripts in a single directory, with different filenames and `package_data`?
- Can I automatically create wheels with filenames that indicate the intended operating system and architecture?
- If not, can I manually change the filenames to do this?

Note that I currently don't plan to maintain separate wheels until the naming convention for Linux wheels is established.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this by modifying the `setup.py` file itself before running it, then renaming the output wheel file to contain the identifier that I wanted it to have. See [here](https://ghostbin.com/paste/mugwy) for code.

Comment: that's creative and does the job... but I hope there is a better way ;)

Comment: The answer is not available any more. :(